# Inter-island flights in Hawaii: Lower 48 ticketing model or bus model?

Tags: air-travel, bookings, hawaii

Do the inter-island flights in Hawaii use

- a ticketing model like the lower 48 states (purchasing far in advance
  is massively cheaper, high fees to change tickets)
- or a "bus model" like the inter-island flights in Trinidad and Tobago
  (show up, buy a ticket, get on the next plane)?

I'm planning an extended trip to the islands, and I'd like to maximize my flexibility by not buying inter-island flights until I have exhausted the charms of the island I'm currently on. But, not if it costs me a fortune to do so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

tl;dr: mainland.

https://www.islandair.com/my-reservation

> All changes are subject to a ticket change fee and difference in fare. Charges are per segment and dependent on fare rules for ticket purchased.

https://www.hawaiianairlines.com/legal/fare-rules-terms-and-conditions

> Interisland Web special fares are valid only for travel between Honolulu and Lihue, Kauai / Kahului, Maui / Kona, Hawaii / Hilo, Hawaii. Changes will be subject to a $30 USD change fee and difference in fare, if applicable.

Mokulele Airlines can't find the similar page but doing one search with them shows Web Specials, Everyday Low Fares w/ a $25 change fee and significantly lower price than the Unrestricted Fares.